# Определить является ли текущее время между заданным +/- 5 минут

Tags: php, datetime, cron, timestamp, crontab

Пишу скрипт для крона.  Задача срабатывать каждый понедельник, среду, пятницу в 10:00. Cron будет запускать этот скрипт каждые 5 минут.

```
$startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$current_plus = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($startTime)));
$current_minus = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 minutes', strtotime($startTime)));

if ((strtotime($current_plus) >= $pn_or_sr_or_pt_10_00) and (strtotime($current_minus) <= $pn_or_sr_or_pt_10_00))
{ 
...
}
```

Как получить это время для сравнения? $pn_or_sr_or_pt_10_00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[date](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) позволяет получить день недели и часы-минуты

```
$check_day = in_array(date('N'), [1,3,5]);
$check_time = date('Hi') < 1005 and date('Hi') > 955;
if ($check_day and $check_time) {
    // code to run
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!